# Ambiguity of a boundary viewed as a linear combination when there is no clear orientation

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hi everyone and please forgive me for unprecise terminology I have started to learn algebraic topology only recently.

Taken from the wikipedia page on Chains :

[image: closed polygonal curve]

I understand the boundary of the above figure to be zero because it can be viewed as (A1-A2) + (A2-A3) + ... + (A5-A1). Another way I understand it is there is only one loop so up to the starting and ending point and chosen direction there is no ambiguity.
However this suppose that there is a path to follow in a way. **How can one understand the boundary of objects that don't have a unique path or that don't have a path**, for example the star graph :
[image: star graph]

Another scenario that I don't understand is the ball $D^3$ when it is constructed from two parts ie with two faces. On the following figure, the boundary of $D^3$ is composed of two 2-Cells, blue (B) and yellow (Y). To define a boundary homomorphism, it seems that one needs to send $D^3$ to B-Y or Y-B but it seems more arbitrary than in the polygonal case. And there could be more than 2 2-cells so **how should one define the linear combination ?**

[image]

Comment: It is true that it is somewhat arbitrary and it bothered me for a very long time, how the simplicial boundary maps are defined. But imagine you need to make a very general definition; you have to fix a choice. To ensure $\partial^2=0$, you then more or less have your hands tied, given a choice of how things work in dimension $1$. Some people justify it in terms of orientation classes on a vector space and viewing, for an $n$ simplex described by $v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_n$, the linearly independent $v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0,\cdots,v_n-v_0$ must fall into a $+/-$ orientation class in the given way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Orienting paths**

To orient "paths" we orient a "universal path". For $e_i$ standard basis vectors, $\Delta^1 = \text{conv}(e_0,e_1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a good candidate.
In particular, letting $\Delta^0 = {e_0}\in \mathbb{R}$, we introduce two inclusions
$$
d_0, d_1\colon \Delta^0 \to \Delta^1, \quad d_0(e_0) = e_1, \, d_1(e_0) = e_0,
$$
where $d_i$ does not hit $e_i$.
We now orient its boundary by giving the $i$-face, which is the image of $d_i$, the sign $(-1)^i$.
Via a continuous map $\varphi \colon \Delta^1\to X$, we are also able to orient the path given by the image of $\varphi$, the points $\varphi(d_0(e_0)), \varphi(d_1(e_0))$ then carry the signs $-1$ and $1$, respectively.

**Higher simplices**

There is a standard functor $s\colon \mathbf{\Delta}\to \mathbf{Top}$ sending $[i]$ to $\Delta^{i}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{i+1}$.
defined e.g. in (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization#OfSimplicialSets).
To orient a general $n$-simplex in nature, we must view it as the image of a  chosen continuous map $\psi\colon \Delta^n\to X$.
Using the functor $s$, the $j$-face of $\psi$ is given by the map $\psi\circ d_j\colon \Delta^{n-1}\to X$, and is oriented by the sign $(-1)^j$.
The choice of $\psi$ influences the signs on the boundary, in an essential way. You can for example always choose to view a path $\varphi\colon \Delta^1\to X$ with the opposite orientation by precomposing with the map $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ on $\Delta^1$.

The only automorphisms of the simplex category $\mathbf{\Delta}$ are the identity as well as the map $r$ reversing all orderings. (https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0608/0608040v4.pdf#page=312)
In this sense, there are only two ways to orient the boundaries of simplices, both consistently disagreeing by a factor of $-1$.

**To your first question:** One first has to *choose* an identification of $\Delta^1$ with a path one finds in nature, *only then* one can talk about signed boundaries.

**To your second question**: What one *should* do is stay consistent, then the only two possibilities simply differ by a factor of -1 throughout.